# How to pass arguments to xslt?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, filter, xsd

Is there any way to pass any argument to xslt? 
For example I need to filter some elements, and I want to be able to change filtering condition.

Preferably without js.

Comment: What language/framework?  I know .NET supports arguments in their XSLT parser.

Comment: In other words, how are you invoking the XSLT stylesheet? That will determine how you can pass parameters to it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, define global parameters in your stylesheet with top-level `<xsl:param name="param-name"/>` elements in your stylesheet, then check the documentation of your favorite XSLT processor API on how to set such parameters before you run a transformation.